# Dropzone is display page contents when hovering over image

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to get Dropzone to work on a asp.net page.  I can drag and drop images without issue, however, when I hover over the image it displays the page contents in the hover dialog.

I've tried a couple of times (vb form page and html) with same results.  The .css and .js files are in place.  Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link href="Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/file-upload"
          class="dropzone"
          id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an working example. Make sure that all resources are loaded successfully.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Dropzone simple example</title>


<!--
  DO NOT SIMPLY COPY THOSE LINES. Download the JS and CSS files from the
  latest release (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/releases/latest), and
  host them yourself!
-->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">


<p>
  This is the most minimal example of Dropzone. The upload in this example
  doesn't work, because there is no actual server to handle the file upload.
</p>

<!-- Change /upload-target to your upload address -->
<form action="/upload-target" class="dropzone"></form>
```